# Multiple $expand Parameters in OData binding

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a table binding and consuming the publicly available OData service from the ES4 SAP system. My root entity set is `ProductSet` and it has 2 navigation properties: `ToSupplier` and `ToSalesOrderLineItems`.

I am able to issue the `$expand` parameter in the table bindings as follows, but could you please assist me in how I can **pass both navigational properties** so that the OData service expands both `ToSupplier` + `ToSalesOrderLineItems`?

```xml
<Table items="{
  path: '/ProductSet',
  parameters: {
    expand: 'ToSupplier'
  }
}">
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
expand: "ToSupplier,ToSalesOrderLineItems"
```

If "ToSupplier" was a parent of "ToSalesOrderLineItems" then it would look like this:

```
expand: "ToSupplier/ToSalesOrderLineItems"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked! (ToSupplier,ToSalesOrderLineItems), I know about expanding between the parent and child but didnt know how to expand multiple nodes at the same level, May I ask is  this documented anywhere in the UI5 SDK?

Comment: I didn't find this in ui5 API, maybe because of $expand is a feature of OData protocol but not the ui5 thing. You can read about it here http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/